# React upload image component not working as expected but API call is fine

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I have a c# webapi which amongst other things, allows a user to upload a profile photo. The Api call is made to a url like:

```
  'https://localhost:7166/User/setphoto?id=3' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'image=@IMG_0439.PNG;type=image/png'
```

This is from Swagger and works fine. I am now trying to implement this on the FE which is in React. First I have my service method:

```
import axios from "axios";
const baseUrl = "https://localhost:7166";
    
export const imageUpload = (image, userId) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("image", image);

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    },
  };

  return axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/User/setphoto?id=${userId}`, formData, config)
    .then((response) => response)
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

And the component itself:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Checkbox, Form, Input, Modal, Radio } from "antd";
import { UploadOutlined, UserOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { message, Upload } from 'antd';
import { CreateOneTaskList } from "../services/TaskListService";
import {imageUpload} from '../services/ImageUploadService'
import "../styles/AddToDo.css";
import { type } from "@testing-library/user-event/dist/type";

const ImageUpload = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [confirmLoading, setConfirmLoading] = useState(false);
  const [modalText, setModalText] = useState("Content of the modal");

  const onFinish = (values) => {
    const userId = localStorage.getItem("signInUserId");
    console.log(values.image);
    if (values.image instanceof File) {
      console.log('values.image is a File');
    } else {
      console.log('values.image is not a File');
    }

    console.log("Success:", values);
    // const reqBody = {
    //   title: values.title,
    // };
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Add form data to the FormData object
    formData.append('image', values.image);

    imageUpload(formData, userId)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        // window.location.reload(true);
        console.log("upload sucess");
        // alert("login sucess");
        setOpen(false);
        window.location.reload(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error adding task: " + error.message);
        alert(error.message);
      });
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log("Failed:", errorInfo);
  };
  const showModal = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleOk = () => {
    setModalText("The modal will be closed after two seconds");
    setConfirmLoading(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setOpen(false);
      setConfirmLoading(false);
    }, 2000);
  };
  const handleCancel = () => {
    console.log("Clicked cancel button");
    setOpen(false);
  };
  

  return (
    <>
      {/* <Button type="primary" className="btn-container" onClick={showModal}>
        Add Profile Image
      </Button> */}
      
      <a onClick={showModal}>
      <UserOutlined /> Profile
      </a>
      

      <Modal
        title="Add Profile Image"
        open={open}
        onOk={handleOk}
        confirmLoading={confirmLoading}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        footer={null}
      >
        {/* <p>{modalText}</p> */}

        <Form
          name="basic"
          labelCol={{
            span: 6,
          }}
          wrapperCol={{
            span: 16,
          }}
          style={{
            maxWidth: 600,
          }}
          initialValues={{
            remember: true,
          }}
          onFinish={onFinish}
          onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
          autoComplete="off"
        >
<Form.Item
  name="image"
  valuePropName="fileList"
  getValueFromEvent={(e) => {
    if (Array.isArray(e)) {
      return e;
    }
    // Convert the event object to a fileList array
    return e && e.fileList;
  }}
>
  <Upload
    maxCount={1}
    beforeUpload={(file, fileList) => {
      // Modify the file here if needed
      const newFileList = [file];
      return newFileList;
    }}
    onChange={(info) => {
      if (info.fileList.length > 1) {
        // Ensure that only one file is selected
        info.fileList.pop();
      }
    }}
  >
    <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>Click to Upload</Button>
  </Upload>
</Form.Item>


          <Form.Item
            wrapperCol={{
              offset: 14,
              span: 16,
            }}
          >
            <Button className="btn-cancel" onClick={handleCancel}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
};
export default ImageUpload;
```

However this does not work as expected. When I run this, it returns the following error:

```
AxiosError {message: 'Request failed with status code 400', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
```

Which I then understood to mean the Image file is not being appended to the request - hence the checks in OnFinish to make sure it is a file. This fails and says values.image is not a file, but I checked the antd documentation and it says it is the correct way to upload a file.

I am not sure where to go from here really, any advice appreciated.